# List broken or pebkac?

Tags: c#

Either the Generic List (and HashSet) is broken or ... pebkac

This unworthy test-program outputs the following:

```
System.Byte[]
6:2 3 4 5 6 7
True        // as expected
System.Byte[]
6:3 4 5 6 7 8
True        // as expected
System.Byte[]
6:3 4 5 6 7 8
False       // oops ... something's very wrong
System.Byte[]
6:3 4 5 6 7 8
False       // oops ... something's very wrong
```

I just don't get it, REALLY don't get it why the last two ones are "False" :-/

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class HashSetTest {

    public static HashSet<byte[]> SomeThing=new HashSet<byte[]>();

    public static void Write(byte[] pebkac) {
        Console.Write("{0}:",pebkac.Length);
        foreach(var i in pebkac) {
            Console.Write("{0} ",i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void Main() {
        byte[] test1= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        byte[] test2= {2,3,4,5,6,7};
        byte[] test3= {3,4,5,6,7,8};

        List<byte> test4=new List<byte>();
        test4.AddRange(test3);

        byte[] test5=new byte[6];
        var i=0;
        foreach(byte j in test3) {
            test5[i++]=j;
        }

        SomeThing.Add(test1);
        SomeThing.Add(test2);
        SomeThing.Add(test3);

        Console.WriteLine(test2);
        Write(test2);
        Console.WriteLine(SomeThing.Contains(test2));

        Console.WriteLine(test3);
        Write(test3);
        Console.WriteLine(SomeThing.Contains(test3));

        Console.WriteLine(test4.ToArray());
        Write(test4.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(SomeThing.Contains(test4.ToArray()));

        Console.WriteLine(test5);
        Write(test5);
        Console.WriteLine(SomeThing.Contains(test5));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Contains` uses reference equality by default. You will need to add you own custom equality comparer to the hashset constructor for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, nothing's broken - but arrays don't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode`. So a `HashSet<byte[]>` is just checking for the presence of the exact object that the key refers to. It's *not* looking for "an array with an equivalent sequence of bytes".

You haven't added `test5` to the set, so `SomeThing.Contains(test5)` won't be true - and calling `SomeThing.Contains(anyListOfByte.ToArray())` will return false because that will create a new array each time.

If you want `HashSet<T>` to use a different meaning of equality, you can do so by passing an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the constructor.

Comment: But isn't test5 identical to test3?

Comment: `byte[] test5=new byte[6];` No. Only equal by their contents. There are two types of "equal". If you wanted them to be *referentially* equal, you would have to do `byte[] test5 = test3;`

Comment: But that's exactly why and where I'm stuck and puzzled. I really DO want to check the content, not reference.

Comment: @giskesus: Then you need to provide an `IEqualityComparer<byte[]>` that does that. You can do it, but that wasn't what you asked :) This answer explains why you're getting the results you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

You're testing reference equality. `test4.ToArray()`, `test5`, and `SomeThing` are all **different objects**.